# Removing just position attribute in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I set up a code that have this traits:

1. the navigation Items-texts- are hidden behind the some Divs I'll call them Navigation Divs
2. when the mouse move over the some of pixels-navigation Divs-, the text that they are behind this, slide right and left and in some cases,  some of them move top and bottom about 15 px with animate() method...
3. when the mouse move to another Div, other text will be reset to first position
   for next action and I did this with:

   ```
   $(document).on('mouseover', '.pixel#p18', function(){
      $('.submenus').not("this Div's TEXT").fadeOut('fast').removeAttr('style');
   });/* this Div's Text is for Example*/
   ```

and I wrote this kind for all of my navigation texts..

Now my problem is:

1. When I hover mouse on one of navigation Divs, some of the texts that they did not animated, become to visible because of removeAttr('style')!!! But I don't want that...
2. is there any alternative way that I can slide the texts or other elements to left, right, top and down with optional values of move...??? for example 23px to left or 17px to top...  etc???- I'm familiyar with slideUp and Down and toggle but not sure that they  are good enough for my code...
3. Do you have some better Idea for this---that actualy you'll have because I think this is very bad
4. and the last Question is that why my codes are very slow in running? the animations that I wrote have lak some times and I'm not Sure that the problem is my selector or other stuff.

Comment: why are you removing the style attribute?

Comment: because I want that the navigation texts was hidden and when the user hover a special Div, the texts become appear!!!

Answer (score 0):

For this you need something like .animate which has a callback. So something like:

```
$('.submenus').not("this Div's TEXT").animate({opacity:0},500,'linear', function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('style');
});
```

This will only remove the attribute when the animation is complete.

Comment: fadeOut has a callback